# Как можно дозаписывать в Excel файл новые данные?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

Есть код, который должен дозаписывать в Excel файл новые данные:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a' )
d = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1],"b":[2],})
d.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="dec")
writer.save()
worksheet = writer.sheets['dec']
#worksheet = writer.sheets['cert']
print(worksheet)
```

Но он выдает ошибку:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Sheet 'dec' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.
```

А также, по возможности, хотел бы дозаписывать в файл через xlsxwriter, а не openpyxl.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Если вам по какой-то причине не подошел ответ, то можно задать уточняющий вопрос под ответом. Пока не принят ни один ответ, создается впечатление, что ваш вопрос все еще открытый и неотвеченный.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `append_df_to_excel()` из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205):

```
append_df_to_excel(filename, d, index=False, sheet_name="dec")
```